# AngularJS 1.4 avoid multiple digest calls and maximum call stack

Tags: angularjs

I'm working in an angular app where Projects have many Parts, and the data structure is being fetched from the server. In Angular, parts don't have a project attribute, just the project_id. Projects have a commission_rate, and I need access to that in order to calculate the actual commission, and total price for a given part.

My thought was to assign the project to each part when the project is fetched from the server. I tried doing the following:

```
angular.forEach(project.parts, function(part) {
    part.project = project;
});
```

but I get a massive amount of Max call size stack exceeded, and 10 digest loops reached errors.

I've also tried using $.extend to shallow copy the project and assign that to part.project, but the end result is the same.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're looping through project.parts then assigning project of each part back to the array you are looping through?  Seems like you intend part.project to be set to something other than project.

Comment: No, I am trying to assign the project to the part, so I can access the project's commission_rate via the part like so: part.project.commission_rate.

Comment: if you have to access the commission_rate from project, then why are you assigning this value to all parts, just use it where you need using main project object.

Comment: The project object isn't always in scope.

Comment: then simply create a commission_rate property on $scope and use it,  maybe I can help you if you can show some code

Comment: That's too little information. This piece of code alone cannot cause the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Because you only provide this small code fragment all I can do is to tell you what I would look for:

In angular's $digest loop all watcher functions are called and the values are compared with their prior state. Angular than repeats the digest loop to make sure there are no changes introduced by the watcher functions themselves. This loop will be continued until no more changes are detected or the loop counter reaches 10. Than angular gives up. (This mechanism is called dirty-checking)

I would try to change your project object before any bindings apply, this could be inside the success function of your $http promise.